# How to get a Text next to a chat message?

Tags: android, textview

How do I get a Text next to the chat message as a status message (SEND) ,the chat message can grow or shrink base on message length but the text should appear next to the chat messages,

Image : https://ibb.co/dsZntk
Image 2 : https://ibb.co/fExwm5

Just like the image show at right side send text ,that is i what I want to achieve

Edited : see in the image two when I inflater the second layout the status send appears in fixed place ,I want that text (send) to appear next to chat message like image 1

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? I'm not really sure what you mean by this. Maybe post a mockup picture or some code you already have tried?

Comment: Yes sir, I have updated my question

Comment: You have to express your problem/issue while developing that. You are asking for development help. Create a `recylerview` list and two layout view for sender and receiver. Just inflate the view for sender and receiver.

Answer (score 0):

How do I get a Text next to the chat message as a status message (SEND) ,the chat message can grow or shrink base on message length but the text should appear next to the chat messages,

I've added a sample xml for your reference which will give you a hint how you can possibly achieve such `Views`. You can copy and paste below source code in `Android-Studio` and understand the design.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="8dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sendMsg"
    android:text="This is sent msg!"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxWidth="240dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textMsgStatus"
    android:text="Sent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    app:layout_editor_absoluteY="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/sendMsg" />
```

PS: Before asking question on SO, try to do lil research by-self. It will help you in long run.:)

Comment: Yes I created two layout and inflated but I am not able to get the text next to chat message see I have updated my question (see image 2)

Comment: How have you used above xml?

Comment: Yes, I created two XML files as left.xml(1TextView with LinearLayout) and right.xml(2 TextView with relatively out) and one list.xml , then I used custom adapter to to inflate the messages to listview as left(received messages) and right(send messages)

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple work I just made my self complicated

I just have to use

android:layout_toleftof="chat messaage" 
Then it automatically align left of each chat messaage